# Excel 2021 does not show spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2021 on Windows 11. It has been working until today, but when I opened a file, it stopped showing the spreadsheet.

Screenshot:
[image]
It's not about zooming issue. It is possible to enter values to cells, but they do not appear because there is no spreadsheet (cells are not visible). The same for all files. Creating a new worksheet is the same. I used "repair" function but it did nothing. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, but nothing changed. Other office programs (Word and PowerPoint) work fine.

Possibly the same as [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/883336/excel-opening-as-a-blank-spreadsheet-but-with-values).

Comment: I installed Windows update today. I don't know if it did anything, but that's the only thing I can think of something is different from yesterday.

Comment: Not sure if related but just check if Hardware Acceleration is ON in Excel Settings and if so Disable it and check again. File -> Options -> Advanced->Display -> Disable HW Graphics Acceleration. It's a toggle switch.

Comment: I disabled HW Graphics Acceleration, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Is the View set to Normal  (View -> Workbook Views -> Normal)?

Comment: Yes, it is set to Normal.

Comment: Only the formula bar works. You cannot do anything with the large blank white area below the formula bar. If you enter a value in A1 from the formula bar, it becomes A2 (after hitting a return key), but the value cannot be seen. If you press the up key, it will become A1, and the value is shown in the formula bar.

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled and if you are comfortable doing restore, try restoring your Windows to a previous state (Restore Point) and check again.

Comment: It seems I did not enable it... I see that I installed KB5015732 today, and KB5015882 yesterday. I used Excel yesterday (and it worked fine), but I don't remember when I installed KB5015882 (before or after using Excel).

Comment: If you go to %appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\ on File Explorer, what the modified date of the file found there?

Comment: The file (Excel15.xlb) in %appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\ is modified today (August 4). But I uninstalled and reinstalled Office today.

Comment: I uninstalled Office 2021 again and installed Office 2019, but Excel 2019 has the same problem... I will uninstall Office 2019 and reinstall Office 2021...

Answer (score 0):

I considered deleting this question, but just in case it is useful for someone else...

I am attaching a screenshot in which a blue arrow is drawn. Clicking the thing pointed by the arrow fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: So you extended the formula bar!!! lol

Comment: It seems like so. But if I intentionally extend it, I don't get the same result as I still see the column labels and other stuffs at the bottom. Uninstalling it not fixing this problem is not very nice...